# How to create subsections with publish in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if there is a way to make a index like showed in the next figure, with Sections and Subsections, employing **Publish** in **MATLAB**.

[image]

Thanks!.

Comment: Looks like it only does sections, not subsections. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use html:

`%% Main Section (H2)
%
% <html><h3> Here is sub-section </h3></html>
%
% comments.`